# Large Download Pi Server

Tags: pi-4, server, file-server

I have a raspberry pi 4 (2gb) set up as a file server. I was wondering if it was possible to create a tool, where when I paste a link into some sort of prompt, my raspberry Pi would download the file to it's hard drive.

Basically, it would have a input, where I paste a file link (https://example.com/example.zip) and it would download the file to a specific folder, then I could move it to my main computer when it was done, at a much higher speed.

Does this exist? / Would it be possible to create my own?

**Edit:**
I used https://github.com/fredthedoggy/Web-PHP-Download-Manger for downloading

Comment: Have you tested [FileRun](http://www.filerun.com/)? – Recently, I have installed and It's really geat.

Comment: @M.Rostami I tried FileRun, but do you know If I can give it a link, and it will automatically download that file?

Comment: Honestly, it just a file server as you said ("*I have a raspberry pi 4 (2gb) set up as a file server*") but I think you mean something else. The thing you are looking for is much related to download manager.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sudo apt install lynx`

Then use

`lynx  https://example.com/example.zip`

Or without installing anything extra

`wget https://example.com/example.zip`

or

`curl https://example.com/example.zip`

Comment: curl will output to stdout by default. You should correct it to `curl https://example.com/example.zip -o example.zip` or `curl https://example.com/example.zip > example.zip`

Comment: or `curl -O https://example.com/example.zip`

Comment: Is it possible to make a PHP page, that asks for a link, and then when I paste one in, it executes the curl command?

Comment: Take a look here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php

Comment: @Dougie that just opens the file in my web browser, it doesn't download it to the server

Comment: Copy the code to your RPi change the names to something that exists that you can experiment with and see what happens.